# Having issues sending an array of bytes using asynchronous socket in C#?

Tags: c#

I 've following one of the .NET tutorials by Microsoft on how to implement an Asynchronous Server Socket. My goal is to implement a new function called writeToClient(byte[] input) inside Microsoft given code.

This function will be executed by another function located in a different application and upon being called, it will received an array of byte as an input and forward it to another application via socket running on a Raspberry Pi using Send() ideally.

The main issue I am facing so far is that Send(Socket handler, string data) function requires two arguments. To this end, I haven't been able to find a way I could combine these two applications into one and achieve my goal.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
namespace UDCManager

{ 
public class StateObject
{
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;

    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
}

public class AsynchronousServerSocket
    {
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void StartListening()
    {
            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Any;

            IPEndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(IP, 24000);
            Socket listner = new Socket(IP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
                listner.Bind(EP);
                listner.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listner.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listner);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
         
         allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }



        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
               
                    // Echo the data back to the client.  
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Send(Socket handler, string data)
    {
       
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);


    }

        **public static void writeToClient(byte[] input)
        {
            
        }**


        public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you'd want something like this

```
// Expose a socket as a private variable, for example
private static Socket _socket;

public static void StartListening()
{
    IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Any;
    IPEndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(IP, 24000);
    _socket = new Socket(IP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); // <<<< HERE
    // ...
}

// then you could use it in the write method
public static void writeToClient(byte[] input)
{
    // validate input for null, and size
    // validate that _socket has been created (optionally)
    _socket.BeginSend(input, 0, input.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler)
}
```

It may be simpler if you could start with synchronous code, and after that is working, convert it to new style async code using async/await